# What does the "+1" in some weapons' shots mean?

Tags: weapons, gurps-4e, gurps

What does the "+1" in some weapons' shots mean?

Take the .45 SMG - it has "50+1(5)" listed under its shots. I know what the "50" and "(5)" mean, but what is the deal with the "+1"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It means you can have an additional round in the gun's chamber, in addition to a full magazine. If this is explained in the ***Basic Set*** I can't find it, but it is on p. 79 of GURPS ***High-Tech***:

> *Shots*: Weapons that can load an additional round directly into the chamber (p. 88) have a “+1” appended to Shots.

This is noted as an addition to the statistics in the Basic Set. The terminology seems to be used to some extent in the real-world firearms community, since I've encountered it in a *Forgotten Weapons* [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JVhSQwlVW4I) on YouTube. I've reported it as errata against the Basic Set.